# "onchange" Handler effect for Custom lookup Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created a custom lookup based on below link:

http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/

Here is my component code:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="conList" type="contact[]" description="Will retrieve contacts from controller" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.conList}" var="con">
<tr>
<td>{!con.Name}</td>
<td><c:customLookup objectAPIName="Account" selectedRecordId="{!con.AccountId}"/></td>
<td>{!con.Account.Email}</td>
<aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

My scenarios:
1) here i need to get the value of account email from account dynamically based on selection of custom look up

Obsevations:
1) On change Dynamic binding is not happening to '{!con.Account.Email}' field unlike other fields.

I'm unable to lock onchange effect of `<c:customLookup />`. 
Tried with `<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.conList}" action="{!c.action}"/>`
But,this action will fires only if i add or remove a contact from the list.
Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple reports that changes are not detected in `aura:iteration`. A couple weeks ago I reported this behaviour back to the lightning repo: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues/128

I would suggest to extend your `c:customLookup` and let it throw a custom change event when it is changed and later handle this in your outer component.

```
<!-- customLookup -->
<aura:registerEvent name="dataChange" type="c:custom_event" />
...
<ui:inputText change="{!c.lkpChanged}" ....
```

Your lookup controller:

```
lkpChanged: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    cmp.getEvent("dataChange").fire();
},
```

And in your outer component you catch and handle it:

```
<aura:handler name="dataChange" event="c:custom_event" action="{!c.dataChanged}" />
```